# WCF tcp.net client/server connection failing "Stream Security is required"

Tags: wcf, connection

I am trying to test a simple WCF tcp.net client/server app.  The WCF service is being hosted on Windows 7 IIS.  I have enabled TCP.net in IIS.  I granted liberal security privileges to service app by configuring an app pool with admin rights and set the IIS service application to run in the context.

I enabled tracing on the service app to troubleshoot. Whenever I run a simple method call against the service from the WCF client app, I get the following exception:

"Stream Security is required at http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, but no security context was negotiated. This is likely caused by the remote endpoint missing a StreamSecurityBindingElement from its binding."

Here is my client configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="InsecureTcp">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here is my service configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="InsecureTcp"  >
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="OrderService" behaviorConfiguration="debugServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"
        contract="ProtoBufWcfService.IOrder" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debugServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 2):

WCF doesn't like insecure communications - it wants to use safe and secure comm channels by default. The default security mode for `netTcpBinding` is transport-level security with Windows credentials. Can you use that default instead of turning everything off??

If your server machine and all the clients calling it are on the same company LAN, behind a firewall, there's really no point in not using Windows credentials. To do so, use this binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="InsecureTcp">
      <security mode="Transport">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

That security feature is very fast, often implemented in hardware on your network card, and using Windows credentials inside an organization typically is the best way to go.

So why did you disable all security on `netTcpBinding` and get yourself into this trouble?

Comment: WCF is a program not a person, to like or unlike things. This is misleading, since it is possible to configure WCF for insecure communication scenarios as well. Furthermore, you do not give the reason for the exception.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen: ok, the **DESIGNERS** of WCF didn't like insecure communications - is that "personal" enough for you?

Comment: Insecure communication (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734784(v=vs.110).aspx) is supported by WCF and is an acceptable scenario for development and testing purposes, or communication that does not require any kind of security. The question did not specify the circumstances of the case, so it cannot be decided whether that specific scenario matches these suggestions. However, the exception and problem in question is still not answered. And I am really interested about the reason of it, since I am experiencing the same error. So, If you know the answer, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Macr_s answer is working for Windows 2008.

Do note when you are trying the above in a local/development Windows 7, things will work with out security.

Please dont modify your APP Pool, leave to default app pool, it is working